# The keyword 'transaction binding' is not supported on this platform?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core

I have a model class in a .Net core 2.0 app, which uses EF core. `D` is a view which accesses the remote server via linked server on the database. (SQL Server 2014)

```
public class D
{
    [Key]
    public int MyId1 { get; set; }
    public int Myxxx { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

However, `_context.D.ToList()` got the error of

> The keyword 'transaction binding' is not supported on this platform

Comment: What database are you using? This is complete guess but I wonder whether EF Core requires a later version of your database.

Comment: sql-server 2014.

Comment: Have a look at your connection string.  Does it mention transaction binding?  This is new to me but a quick search threw up [this](https://weblogs.asp.net/ryangaraygay/issue-with-system-transactions-sqlconnection-and-timeout).  I wonder whether that attribute has been included in your connection string but is not supported for some reason.

Comment: @ca9163d9 Unfortunately you deleted your question. Anyway you could use [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=53e8366d3a0124cd5caa0d113440b5d3)